# WSO2 Application Server: Distinguish duplicate method names

Tags: java, wso2, axis, application-server

for a project at university I am trying to set up a quite simple HelloWorld-Service on a WSO2 Application Server v5.01. It contains an interface and a class with three methods.

Interface:

```
public interface HelloWorld {
  public String helloWorld();
  public String sayHello(String name);
  public String sayHello(String name, String surename);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

  @Override
  public String helloWorld() {
    return "Hello World!";
  }

  @Override
  public String sayHello(String name) {
    return "Hello " + name;
  }

  @Override
  public String sayHello(String name, String surname) {
    return "Hello " + name + " " + surname;
  }
}
```

As you can see the implementation contains two methods with the same name. If I upload this packaged as aar-file the service just offers the second method signature. How can I tell the service to offer both? 
Are there any annotations I can add or how would one do that?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

many remoting implementations do not support overloading methods (same name, differnt args).
Just avoid it by makeing the method name of your sayHello methods different to each other

Comment: As WSO2 AS supports annotations for JAX-WS where you can define the published method names (and afaik can map different in-code method signatures to different published method names), I hoped that there could be similar solutions for the AAR-way.

Comment: Ok, maybe add this to your question. In general I think it is not important, one can easily live with that limit ..

Answer (score 0):

You have used Axis2 as your web service engine and Axis2 does not support for operation overloading. AS some mentioned it is discourage to use operation overloading in web services.